# Field is inaccessible in this context

Tags: soql, managed-package, query, dynamic-soql, work-order

We have a managed package app which makes dynamic queries where the customer can set which fields to query on an object.

The customer has enabled in her org the service called 'Field Service Lightning', so the `WorkOrder` standard object is enabled.

The customer created a lookup on our packaged `bt_stripe__Transaction__c` object to the `WorkOrder` object, and set the app to dynamically query that field.

When the query is made, we are getting the following error:

> Error in query: Field bt_stripe__Transaction__c.WorkOrder__c is inaccessible in this context

My guess is that this is happening because our packaged app doesn't have the access to the `WorkOrder` object, so querying the lookup fails.

Is there any way to query these fields from the namespace-context?

Comment: How does your dynamic query looks like, ideally it should not be a problem.

Comment: please share the SOQL query, and tell us how do you run it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the API version of your class that makes the dynamic query. The Work Order object was introduced in API v36.0, so if your class is v35.0 or earlier, it will not be aware of the existence of the Work Order object.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_workorder.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are can be couple of things that can cause this.

- The running user doesn't have access to the WorkOrder__c field. Fix would be giving them access field  / object
- If WorkOrder__c is a formula field, it might be referencing some fields that user might not have access.